# Switched my PHP loaders from jQuery to Fetch and now none of my JS is working with them

Tags: javascript

I switched all my loaders from jQuery to Fetch and now none of the sliders are working but the slides themselves are showing up correctly in the DOM. I just can't seem to target them with JS.

https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/whoward-dev-area/dev-index.php

```
fetch('/_resources/php/dev-home-interrupter-loader.php')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(body) {
    document.querySelector('#home-interrupter').innerHTML = body;
  });

    const interrupterslidesContainer = document.getElementById("interrupter-slides-container");
    const interrupterslide = document.querySelector(".interrupter-slide");
    const previnterrupter = document.getElementById("interrupter-slide-arrow-prev");
    const nextinterrupter = document.getElementById("interrupter-slide-arrow-next");

    nextinterrupter.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const interrupterslideWidth = interrupterslide.clientWidth;
      interrupterslidesContainer.scrollLeft += interrupterslideWidth;
    });

    previnterrupter.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const interrupterslideWidth = interrupterslide.clientWidth;
      interrupterslidesContainer.scrollLeft -= interrupterslideWidth;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs before the fetch even starts

```
fetch('/_resources/php/dev-home-interrupter-loader.php')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(body) {
    document.querySelector('#home-interrupter').innerHTML = body;
  })
  .then(() => {
    const interrupterslidesContainer = document.getElementById("interrupter-slides-container");
    const interrupterslide = document.querySelector(".interrupter-slide");
    const previnterrupter = document.getElementById("interrupter-slide-arrow-prev");
    const nextinterrupter = document.getElementById("interrupter-slide-arrow-next");

    nextinterrupter.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const interrupterslideWidth = interrupterslide.clientWidth;
      interrupterslidesContainer.scrollLeft += interrupterslideWidth;
    });

    previnterrupter.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const interrupterslideWidth = interrupterslide.clientWidth;
      interrupterslidesContainer.scrollLeft -= interrupterslideWidth;
    });
})
```

Comment: very true, but there is no need for a further `.then` before running all that synchronous code - it will still work if all that code is moved up inside the `function(body)` in the second `.then`.

Comment: True, I just did it for readability

Comment: OK, although I'm not sure how it helps readability to make it looks like something (the `document.querySelector` call in this case) is asynchronous when it's not.

Comment: Thanks, Konrad you were spot on as to the problem.